# $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, monotonically increasing, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $L$ is an upper bound.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ be differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, monotonically increasing, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L, L \in \mathbb{R}$. How can I prove that $L$ is an upper bound?

### My attempt:

If $L$ is not an upper bound, $\exists c \in \mathbb{R}: f(c) > L$ therefore, by definition of limit, $\exists b \in \mathbb{R}, b > c, f(c) > f(b) > L $ Namely - $f(b)$ is closer to the limit, as defined by the limit definition.

Therefore, because the function is differentiable and hence continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ it must be that it goes "down" to $b$ from $c$, and it is in contradiction with the fact that $f$ is monotonically increasing.

Is there a simpler prove? Maybe a sentence? Is this proof even fine?

Thanks.

Comment: Another way to finish: since $f$ is increasing, $f(x)\geq f(c)>L$ for $x\geq c$. This contradicts $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$. Differentiability is not needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in \mathbb R$. Now since $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb R$, $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb R$. Additionally, note that since $f$ is monotone increasing, we may conclude that $\forall y \in \mathbb R$ with $y<x, f(y)<f(x)$. From here I would suggest that you use the formal definition of a limit, as I will put below. I don't know how rigorous your argument must be, but I would suggest using formal definitions here as much as possible.

Definition of the limit: (at infinity)

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N >0$ such that $\forall x \in 
\mathbb R$ with $x>N$, $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$